# Must declare scalar variable, updating datagrid view for user logged in

Tags: c#, sql

These are the tables in my project:

[image: Users table]

[image: Records table]

I am trying to update a `DataGridView` so that it displays the data of the user who is logged in.

I am getting the error: *'Must declare scalar variable '@CurrentUserID'...* I think this is because I cannot convert the value to an `int` but if this is the case how do I fix the problem?

This is my code so far:

```
//Find ID of user who is logged in
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\n0740572\Projects\newest\CW\CW\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select UserID from Users where Username = '"+loggedInLabel.Text+"' ", conn);
try
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        int currentUserID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("UserID"));
        command.Parameters.Add("@CurrentUserID", SqlDbType.Int);
        command.Parameters["@CurrentUserID"].Value = currentUserID;

        //update datagridview
        string dgvconn = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\n0740572\Projects\newest\CW\CW\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        string sql = "select * from Records where UserID = @CurrentUserID";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dgvconn);
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds, "Records");
        connection.Close();
        dataGridView.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView.DataMember = "Records";

    }
    reader.Close();
} 
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
} 
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: if your first command returns only single value then why you are not using `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: You don't use `command` to fill the `dataadapter`, just the `sql`. As a result it has no idea that there's parameters to contend with. Your *actual* `command`, on the other hand, is subject to SQL injection, which is bad. Don't reuse instances and use `using` consistently (then you won't need to `.Close()` anything, not even in a `finally`).

Comment: I am sorry I am new to all this and I am a bit confused by what you are saying. How would I alter the code ?

Comment: I changed the code where I add the parameter to this: dataadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentUserID", currentUserID); and it fixed it... Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else was stuck with it.

I solved it by removed the code where I added the parameters and replacing it with :

```
dataadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentUserID", currentUserID);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `AddWithValue` is evil (better than nothing tho). https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors in your code, you're not disposing anything and ***re-using the command in a invalid way (while the reader is executing)***.

You're not using parameters. You're not re-using the SQL Connection. You're not adding parameters in the correct way.

### This is how the code should look

```
try
{
    DataSet records = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\n0740572\Projects\newest\CW\CW\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        int? userId = null;
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select UserID from Users where Username = @Username", conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = loggedInLabel.Text;

            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                if (reader.Read())
                    userId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("UserID"));
            conn.Close();
        }      

        if (userId == null) // No row found
            throw new ApplicationException("User not found");

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Records where UserID = @CurrentUserID", conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@CurrentUserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = userID.Value;

            // SqlDataAdapter opens and closes the connection itself.
            using (SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                dataadapter.Fill(records , "Records");
        }
    }

    //update datagridview    
    dataGridView.DataSource = records ;
    dataGridView.DataMember = "Records";
} 
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

---

### You should also combine SQL Queries

`select UserID from Users where Username = @Username` and `select * from Records where UserID = @CurrentUserID` can be combined into this:

```sql
select Records.*
from Records
join Users
    on Users.UserID = Records.UserID
where Users.Username = @Username
```

Then you only have to supply the Username and you'll get the records if everything is there.